# get number of followers of twitter account by scraping twitter

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I tried to get the number of followers of a given Twitter account by scraping twitter. I tried scraping with BeautifulSoup and XPath. But none of the code is working.

This is some of my sample testing code for it,

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

url = "https://twitter.com/BarackObama"
resposnse = re.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resposnse.content)
div_tag = soup.find_all('main',{"class":"css-1dbjc4n r-1habvwh r-16xksha r-1wbh5a2"})
```

when i try to see what is the content i scraped by using below code,

```
import requests
t=requests.get('https://twitter.com/BarackObama')
print(t.content)
```

It's not included any of the data like count of followers or anything.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: any reason to not use their API instead? [User Object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/user-object) has property `followers_count`

Comment: yes I want to do this by scrapping their web instead of API call.

Comment: alright, good luck.

Answer (score 3):

whenever your code started to parse information from the twitter URL. it will parse all data suddenly but it won't get all the data. because the URL page is loaded but not the values or other important data etc... (same for the followers). so there is **TWITTER PYTHON API** where you can able to get followers with [*api.GetFollowers()*](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter.html)

Answer (score 0):

The relevant API endpoint is `followers/ids`. Using [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) you can do the following:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI, TwitterPager
api = TwitterAPI(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, 
                 YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                 YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
                 YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
count = 0
r = TwitterPager(api, 'followers/ids')
for item in r.get_iterator():
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```